# Timezone conflict in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, timezone

In third party applications from Different Timezone users are sending data to my Application. I need to take their system's local timezone. Is there any way to do it?

**NOTE:** I cannot send the timezone through Javascript because I can get only data from third party web Application

Comment: There are MANY questions on this subject on StackOverflow and elsewhere on the internet.  Please search before asking.  You might want to start by reading [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-time-zone-best-practices), [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), and [here](http://nodatime.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What information do you have from these third party applications? If the data they send contains any current (local) time information you can calculate the offset with your current application time. If that's not available you can use the remote IP address from the third party application to determine their location (and hence their time zone). Use IP geolocation for this, for example the free [GeoLite](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) downloadable database seems to be suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Time zone != Offset.  Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info